# How to return list of multiple IDs form select2, to my controller via ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

I am using the Select2 control to populate a select this way

```
ViewData["Categories"] = new SelectList(categories, "Id", "Title");

<label asp-for="Categories" class="control-label"></label>
<select asp-for="CategoriesId" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"></select>
```

My ViewModel

```
[Display(Name = "Categories")]
[Required]
public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public List<int> CategoriesId { get; set; }
```

My Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] Models.NewsAlertViewModel NewsAlertViewModel)
```

I've tried returning the IDs as

```
public string CategoriesId { get; set; }
public List<SelectItem> CategoriesId { get; set; }
```

Everything comes in as Null or Count = 0

Comment: try change public List<int> CategoriesId to public List<string> CategoriesId

Comment: Wow, that was it. Sigh, so close yet so far.  Thx friend.

Comment: All from html form except type=number seems to be mapped as string. I am glad to help.

Comment: @TimCadieux `public List<int> CategoriesId`- is not working while posting the form?

Comment: @TanvirArjel - I could not get it to return anything with List<int> but it does work with List<string>

Comment: Then may be `Select2` is setting the option value as string.

Comment: @TanvirArjel It is working now as string

Comment: @TimCadieux Then this is due the `Select2`. You can convert the `string` to `int` in controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Basic `TypeConverter` bind types same as defined in html input. Eg. `int`,`decimal` etc. will work only for *`<input type="number">`* all others will be string. And `Select` has string values so you need to define as `string`.

Also you can write your own [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) to bind what you want how you want.

[Article that describe Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
Read the section **Default model binder limitations**